# Машинное обучение с помощью линейной регрессии

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Возник вопрос касательно машинного обучения с помощью библиотеки SkLearn. Я подгружаю все необходимые библиотеки. Суть задания: у меня есть таблица с данными о людях страдающих или не страдающих диабетом. То есть в несколько столбцов у меня характеристика людей, их возраст, характеристика кожи, крови и последний столбец отвечает за то, есть ли у них диабет или нет(True or False)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

Здесь я читаю сам файл и разделяю, параметры характеризующие здоровье человека кладу в Х, а то что должно получится на выходе кладу в Y(то есть Y это болен он диабетом или нет). Также  я здесь перевожу true и false в 1 и 0. И все массивы еще также перевожу в numpy для удобства работы с библиотекой.

```
table = pd.read_csv("Diabet.csv")

Y=table[['diabetes']]
del table['diabetes']
print(Y[:5])
table.head()


Y = Y.applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else 0)
X=np.asarray(table)
Y=np.asarray(Y)
print(Y[:10])
print(X[:10])
```

Здесь я применяю модель линейной регрессии. Обучаю массивы характеристик Х и выходной массив Y. Дальше я хочу проверить, правильно ли работает мой код. И хочу сравнить значения пациента номер 6 (за него отвечает переменная needToPredict). По условию у этого человека диабет, соответственно ему соответствует цифра 1. Но программа возвращает мне значение 0.0573623, то бишь диабета у него нет. В чем я ошибся, может кто объяснить?

```
model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(X,Y)

needToPredict=X[6].reshape(1,-1)

print(needToPredict)
print(Y[6])
yfit = model.predict(needToPredict)
print(yfit)
```

Файл для работы https://www.sendspace.com/file/fad19d

Comment: А ничего, что у вас по сути не задача регрессии, а задача классификации?  И то, что  в такой более чем  странной ситуации линейный регрессор дает не совсем адекватный результат - вполне нормально?

Comment: А что выводят другие ваши команды, хотелось бы посмотреть. В scikit-learn dataset diabetes имеет совсем другой таргет, так что хотелось бы посмотреть, что там у вас вообще в данных и таргете.